# Estimate π of zero inflated Poisson

Tags: expected-value, zero-inflation

Can anyone show how to estimated the **π** of the zero-inflated-Poisson?

> f(y)=π+(1−π)e^(−λ), if y=0;
>
> > =(1−π)*λ^y*e^(−λ)/y!, if y=1,2....

where **π** is the probability that the observation is zero by a binomial process and **λ** is the mean of the Poisson.
[image: zero inflated Poisson]

I use **zeroinfl** to get the estimated coefficients, but I do not know how to get **π**:

> zeroinfl(formula = Lambda ~ Profil + Trace + Larg + Long + Reg + Vit + Racc + Momcorr | Profil + Trace + Larg + Long + Reg + 
>       Vit + Racc + Momcorr, data = LambdaData)
>
> Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
>
> ```
>              Estimate     Std. Error   z value  Pr(>|z|) 
> (Intercept)  -5.320e+00    1.263e+00  -4.212   2.53e-05 
>  Profil       5.560e-02    2.098e-01   0.265   0.790958    
>  Trace        3.455e-01    1.013e-01   3.409   0.000652
>  Larg         3.630e-02    6.828e-02   0.532   0.594990    
>  Long         5.674e-03    1.826e-02   0.311   0.756018    
>  Reg         -2.828e-02    7.315e-01  -0.039   0.969163    
>  Vit          4.495e-05    2.629e-03   0.017   0.986358    
>  Racc         5.281e-01    4.964e-01   1.064   0.287449    
>  Momcorr      3.699e-03    6.009e-04   6.156   7.48e-10
> ```
>
> Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
>
> ```
>             Estimate   Std. Error   z value  Pr(>|z|)  
> (Intercept)  7.070353     1.990167   3.553   0.000381 
> Profil       0.678794     0.435449   1.559   0.119035    
> Trace        0.203185     0.250496   0.811   0.417291    
> Larg        -0.340889     0.191298  -1.782   0.074753   
> Long        -0.041204     0.065708  -0.627   0.530607    
> Reg         -3.507487     1.522579  -2.304   0.021242   
> Vit         -0.011700     0.005227  -2.238   0.025203   
> Racc        -0.336626     1.135956  -0.296   0.766973    
> Momcorr     -0.025258     0.012428  -2.032   0.042120
> ```
>
> Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 68 
>   Log-likelihood: -2589 on 18 Df

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  Can you clarify if you are trying to calculate it manually or obtain it from the package you are using?  Note that if you are asking about how to obtain it from your statistical package that it is [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site, and may be closed

Comment: I think there is a way to calculate it through the estimation results of "zeroinfl" function.

Answer (score 1):

In `zeroinfl()` link functions are used to link the two parameters $\lambda$ and $\pi$ to the two sets of regressors $x$ and $z$. By default (as in your example), log and logit link functions are used, i.e., $\log(\lambda) = x^\top \beta$ and $\text{logit}(\pi) = z^\top \beta$. This is explained in `vignette("countreg", package = "pscl")` in Section 2.3. In your case $x = z$.

To obtain predictions for $\lambda$ and $\pi$ from a fitted `zeroinfl` object, `obj` say, you can use `predict(obj, type = "count")` and `predict(obj, type = "zero")`, respectively. Note that these are different from `predict(obj, type = "response")` (the expectation of the zero-inflated response) and `predict(obj, type = "prob")[,1]` (the probability of observing a zero).