# Zero-inflated Model

Tags: categorical-data

Here we have the zero-inflated model results from the R package `pscl`. However, I am not sure how to use the results to write in the form of the definition of the zero-inflated model. How do I use these coefficient estimates to write out the equation:

$$
Pr(Y_j = 0) = \pi + (1 - \pi) e^{-\lambda}
$$

$$
Pr(y_j = h_i) = (1 - \pi) \frac{\lambda^{h_i} e^{-\lambda}}{h_i!} (h_i > 0)
$$

```
m1 <- zeroinfl(panic ~ Age + gender + married + divorce | gender, data = nlaas)
summary(m1)
## Call:
## zeroinfl(formula = panic ~ Age + gender + married + divorce | gender, data = nlaas)
## 
## Pearson residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q    Max
## -0.4001 -0.3939 -0.2709 -0.2666 6.3065
## 
## Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)  2.207453   0.102296  21.579   <2e-16 ***
## Age          0.018110   0.002068   8.758   <2e-16 ***
## gender      -0.061713   0.064100  -0.963    0.336
## married      0.202641   0.083279   2.433    0.015 *
## divorce      0.132976   0.125871   1.056    0.291
## 
## Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept)   1.8031     0.1627  11.082  < 2e-16 ***
## gender        0.7754     0.2996   2.588  0.00965 **
```

Comment: I have edited the formulas in from the images you linked to so that the question is self-contained. Please check them for accuracy. More importantly are you absolutely sure you have the model and the formula correctly matched up? You stated you were using zero-inflation but I do not think that is what you quoted.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Count model coefficients (poisson with log link) and Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link)

Comment: It (the formula) looks more like a hurdle model to me but I may be mistaken.

Comment: It is a zero-inflated Poisson model. The $\pi$ is the zero-inflation probability and $\exp(-\lambda)$ is the probability for zero from the Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question (and answer) is very similar to this: [Estimate π of zero inflated Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245051/estimate-%CF%80-of-zero-inflated-poisson/246685#246685)

The two parameters $\lambda$ and $\pi$ are described through regressors with the link functions indicated in the summary output. In your case:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\log(\lambda) & = & 2.207 + 0.018 \cdot \text{Age} - 0.062 \cdot \text{gender} + 0.203 \cdot \text{married} + 0.133 \cdot \text{divorce} \\
\text{logit}(\pi) & = & 1.803 + 0.775 \cdot \text{gender}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Both predictions can be easily obtained from `m1` using `predict(m1, type = "count")` or `predict(m1, type = "zero")`, respectively. A few further details are in the answer linked above.